# A program using class template, pair, vector

Tags: class, templates, c++11, vector, std-pair

I'm trying to program the following:
A template class `map` having a pointer to a vector that contains elements `std::pair<T,Q>`, where `T` and `Q` are template types. It's supposed to work similarly to `std::map` and `T` is 'key' type, whereas `Q` stands for 'value' type.  Besides the following should be implemented:
 1. Constructor & destructor.
 2. Function `empty` returning `bool` (if the object is empty).
 3. Function `size` (using `count_if`)
 4. Function `clear` that deletes all vector records.
 5. Operator `[]` which allows for: `map["PI_value"] = 3.14;` It should use function `find`
 6. Operators `=`, `==`, `!=`, `>>` (using `equal` function)

I've been trying to code the above task, but have stuck on the code below.
Do you have any ideas to repair this mess?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename Q>
class mapa
{
private:
    vector<std::pair<T,Q>>* ptr;
    public:
    /**< DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR/////////////////////////// */
    mapa()
    {
        ptr = new vector<std::pair<T,Q>>;
        ptr->push_back(std::pair<T,Q>(0,0));
    }
    /**< DESTRUCTOR////////////////////////////////////// */
    ~mapa(){ delete ptr;}
    /**< EMPTY()////////////////////////////// */
    bool empty()
    {
        if(ptr)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    /**< SIZE()///////////////////////////////// */
    int size()
    {
        return ptr->size();
    }
    /**< CLEAR()///////////////////////////////// */
    void clear()
    {
        ptr->clear(ptr->begin(), ptr->end());
    }
    /**< OPERATOR[]/////////////////////////////////////////// */
    vector<std::pair<T,Q>>* & operator[](T key)
        {
        auto ptr2 = ptr;
        if(empty())
        {
            std::pair<T,Q> para;

            para.first = key;
            para.second = 0;
          ptr2->push_back(para);
          //ptr2->push_back(std::pair<T,Q>(key,0));
        }
        else
        {

            auto ptr2 = find_if( ptr->begin(), ptr->end(),
            [](std::pair<T,Q> example,T key)
                            {
                               return(example.first==key);
                            }
                            );
        }
        return ptr2;
    }
}; //class end
```

Comment: Your `empty()` function will always return `true` unless the memory allocation of the vector fails.

Comment: And that leads to another thing: Why use a pointer for the vector at all?

Comment: Why `ptr` a pointer, why insert `{0, 0}` in constructor, `empty` is wrong. `operator []` should return `Q&` ...

Answer (score 0):

The lambda provided to `std::find_if` is declared wrong.

If you see e.g. [this reference for `std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), you will see that the functions should be like

> ```
> bool pred(const Type &a)
> ```

That means the lambda should be something like

```
[&key](const std:pair<T, Q>& element) { return element.first == key }
```

There are also other problems with your `operator[]` function, like that it should return `Q&` instead of a reference to the vector pointer. You should also remember that `std::find_if` returns an iterator to the found element, or `end()` if not found.